# Can I do task parallelism on GPU with C++ AMP?

Tags: c++-amp

For example, if I have two tasks for GPU, each of which can break into 100 threads, while my graphics card have thousands of cores. Now I dispatch the two tasks with parallel_for_each, on a gaming card like AMD R9 280, will the two task be executed in parallel or one after one?

And for my case, those tasks are actually of a same kernel. Is it possible the GPU would mix tasks of a same kernel but different data?

Fortunately, I can pack those tasks into a single task with one more dimension for the problem I'm dealing with. But it'd save me a lot of time if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Tahiti GPU can support two tasks running concurrently (two single threaded ACE's). While newer AMD GPU can support more (multiple multithreaded ACE's).